# does the oleobject in pb have defined the method open(ref string)?

Tags: powerbuilder

I got the error

> Error calling external object function open at line "hObj.Open(ref sOut)"

when I run those code in PowerBuilder 11.5, here is the code:

```
string sOut

hObj.Open(ref sOut)

oleobject objXMLDOM
objXMLDOM = GetXmlDom(sOut)

Boolean bRet
bRet = CheckOutputState(objXMLDOM)
```

This code is from a function. The param is (`ref oleobject hobj`)

I have these questions:

1. What's the use of string `sOut`? When i run this program, string `sOut` is null, and occurs an null reference error.
2. Does the system defined the method `open(ref string)` already? But when I search the documentation of pb, I haven't find this method was defined, can any one give me some direction, thanks.

Comment: the error text is: Error calling external object function open at line "hObj.Open(ref sOut)"

Comment: What ole object is created and passed? Each ole object has different methods and properties.

Comment: they just declare it in instanse variables, like this : oleobject hObj, i don't know what kind of type it is , and where it was passed. thank you for any .

Comment: You will need to trace to find where the OLEOBJECT is created to determine acceptable methods for the OLEOBJECT.

You can also provide error handling with TRY-CATCH block or ocx_error , ExternalException, Error events of OLEOBJECT


More information here
    PowerBuilder 12.5 > Application Techniques > Using OLE in an Application > OLE objects in scripts

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37774.1250/html/apptech/X_ref348260087.htm

Comment: this help me alot , teach me a way to deal with those errors,  thank you, Eric!

Answer (score 0):

All the function calls must be preceeded by object. For example object.Open.